# how to take screen shots of full scroll view in android bigger than screen

Tags: android, android-layout, screenshot

I have built a `tablelayout` which is basically done by `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. I made the user can scroll the view

Now i want to take  the  screen, shots of the full scroll view  The probleme is: The view is nearly always bigger than the screen.

Is there a way to make a screenshot of the whole `scrollview` layout? If not what do you think can do the job?
Please anyone help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is technically impossible - a screenshot is of the screen only. You need to work out a way of capturing individual chunks of the listview, based on screen resolution, and stitch them together.

Comment: how can stitch them together sir actually i have 8 different different screen

Comment: You want to take the screenshot programmatically?

Comment: this link not full fill my requirement i tried this but i got only on screen image not off

Comment: yes i want screenshots problematically but my view is larger than screen i want full screenshots of the view...hasan

Comment: i find my solution this is the solution for taking screen shots of a scroll which is not visible on screenTableLayout tabLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.allview);
  if (tabLayout != null) {
   Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(tabLayout.getWidth(),
     tabLayout.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
   Canvas b = new Canvas(image);
   tabLayout.draw(b);